# how to change the brace pattern {} in visual studio code, for the C# language

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code

The C# language pattern in Visual Studio Code will be the curly braces {} at the bottom of the code, I want to open it at the front, similar to what it is in JavaScript, as I'm already used to, below I left an example of the C# pattern

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
  internal class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      System.Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't do that.  The brace style you have illustrated is the one everyone else uses in C#.  Your goal should be to get used to that brace style.

Comment: If anything, I'd encourage you to want your C# and JavaScript code to readily look different. It'll encourage you to "switch mindset" and remind you that they are different languages and won't always act similarly.

Comment: I use K&R style braces in C# in personal projects (because I find it annoying to waste so much screen space for braces), but Allman style when I work with others (because it's the convention). Nowadays you can configure stuff like that easily per project anyway. Don't let people here cramp your style!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use .editorconfig file to manage this. Add it to the root of the project (solution) and set [`csharp_new_line_before_open_brace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/style-rules/csharp-formatting-options#csharp_new_line_before_open_brace) to `none`:

```
[*.cs]
csharp_new_line_before_open_brace = none
```

But note that the default style for C# projects is placing braces on new lines and it is used by majority AFAIK (but not all). See the [Common C# code conventions: Style guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/coding-style/coding-conventions#style-guidelines) doc:

> Use the "Allman" style for braces: open and closing brace its own new line. Braces line up with current indentation level.

See also:

1. [C# formatting options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/style-rules/csharp-formatting-options)
2. [Code-style rule options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/code-style-rule-options)